# Strange lines in Canvas with Transformation Matrix

Tags: html, animation, canvas, matrix

I'm new in drawing with HTML5 canvas, now, I've done the following demo:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/4423757/demo2Canvas.html

so here are my questions:

- How can I make disappear the red lines in the silver shadow?
- Should use SVG in this case?

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 0):

You should not use SVG because it is much harder to make animations and SVG is not even efficient for that.

About the main problem, I couldn't solve it but I think that it is caused due to the fact that the shadows are being drawn in exactly the same place has the "155%" are. So to solve this, assuming I'm correct, the shadows need to be thicker.